# AngularJS scope and service

Tags: angularjs

I am using a factory to return 2 elements of an array. In my controller, I populate the 3rd element and use 'unshift' to add it to the first position.

My question is about below scenario. The factory is a singleton and will always contain 2 elements in the Array, however when I refresh the controller and put the breakpoint on 'vm.contacts' which calls the factory , it shows 3 elements while I always expect it to have initial state of 2 elements.

```
function settingsController($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, settingsFactory) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.contacts=[];        
        init();

        function init() {
            var primaryContact = {
                "order": 1,
                "id" : $rootScope.app.user.id,
                "firstName": $rootScope.app.user.firstName,
                "lastName": $rootScope.app.user.lastName,
                "phone": $rootScope.app.user.phone,
                "isActive": true
            }

            vm.contacts = settingsFactory.getContacts();
            vm.contacts.unshift(primaryContact);
         }
}

function settingsFactory() {
        var _service, contacts;
        contacts = [
            {
                 "order": 2,
                 "id" : "1001",
                 "firstName": "",
                 "lastName":"",
                 "phone":"",
                 "isActive": false
             },
             {
                "order": 3,
                "id" : "1002",
                "firstName": "",
                "lastName":"",
                "phone":"",
                "isActive": false
            }
        ];
        _service = {
            getContacts: getContacts,
            getContact: getContact,
            addContact: addContact,
            updateContact: updateContact
        };

        return _service;

        function getContacts() {
            return contacts;
    }

        function updateContact(contactId, info) {
         for(var i in contacts) {
            if(contacts[i].id === contactId) {
                contacts[i].firstName = info.firstName;
                contacts[i].middleName = info.middleName;
                contacts[i].lastName = info.lastName;
                contacts[i].phone = info.phone;
                contacts[i].isActive = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The most important part, i.e. the implementation of getContacts(), is not in your question. But I guess it returns `contacts`, without making a copy. So any component getting the array gets the unique array stored in the service, and is free to modify it. Create a copy, and return that copy instead.

Comment: But I am not adding any new element to the array in the factory. I use get and update methods. I still don't understand.

Comment: @JBNizet I modified to return a copy, but now update method does not work. vm.contacts = angular.copy(settingsFactory.getContacts());
            vm.contacts.unshift(primaryContact);

Comment: The service has a reference to an array. It provides a reference to that array to the component. So the component now has another reference to the same array. It uses it to add an element to the array. So now the array contains a third element, and is referenced by the component and the service. Note that your servce still doesn't return a copy. You're creating a copy in the component. So the next component forgetting to do that will cause the same bug to happen. I have no idea what the update method is supposed to do.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the explanation. I understand that the reference returned to controller from the factory points to same Array. But if we return a copy from the factory, the controller can display the items on the view, but when I want to update any item and call update on the factory it will not work since we are using a copy.